# Access internal method from child namespace

Tags: c++-cli

In C++/Cli is it possible to access an internal method from a child namespace without reflection?

Example:

```
//TestClass.h
namespace Test {
    public ref class TestClass {
    internal:
        void InternalMethod();
    };
}

//ChildClass.h
namespace Test {
    namespace Child {
        public ref class TestClass {
        public:
            void AccessInternalMethod()
            {
                TestClass c;
                c.InternalMethod();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Seems like this should be possible. Sorry if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++/CLI `internal` (as well as C# `internal` and the CLI equivalent `assembly`) doesn't have anything to do with namespaces. When you use that modifier on a member, it means it's accessible from inside the same *assembly*, as the one where it is declared.

That means that if `Test.Child.TestClass` is in the same assembly as `Test.TestClass`, it can access `InternalMethod()`. If it's in another assembly, it can't access it. Namespaces have nothing to do with that.

Comment: I was a little premature, there was another compiler error that was causing InternalMethod to not be found. Me = stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Svick = glad to help + hopes Kyle enjoys SWTOR too.